# Autohotkey if statement isn't working

Tags: autohotkey

My `if` statement on line 8 isn't working. Even though the `Msgbox` of %Width% shows 3200 I always get the "width is not 3200" message box. Changing the `if` to == and putting checking for "3200" rather than 3200 has no effect.

I've also put the `if` statement inside the `activeMonitorInfo` method and it shows the same behaviour in there.

```
#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

activeMonitorInfo( X, Y, Width, Height ) 
Msgbox %Width%

if ( %Width% = 3200 ) {
    msgbox "Width is 3200"
    return
} else {
    msgbox "Width is not 3200"
    return
}

activeMonitorInfo( ByRef X, ByRef Y, ByRef Width, ByRef Height )
{
    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, mouseX , mouseY
    SysGet, monCount, MonitorCount
    Loop %monCount%
    {   
        SysGet, curMon, Monitor, %a_index%
        if ( mouseX >= curMonLeft and mouseX <= curMonRight and mouseY >= curMonTop and mouseY <= curMonBottom ) {
                X      := curMonTop
                y      := curMonLeft
                Height := curMonBottom - curMonTop
                Width  := curMonRight  - curMonLeft
                return
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit the percent signs:

```
if ( Width = 3200 ) {
```

Same as

```
if width = 3200
{
```

same as

```
if(width=="3200") {
```

but for some reasons, `if width == 3200` or `if width = "3200"` will not work. I simply only use the very first method above, nothing can go wrong there.

In Ahk, you only need `%`s if the documentation explicitly asks you for a `value` (or name, text, number, etc.).

Also, use percent signs in literal assigments: `a = %width%`. However, not when you use the expression assignment: `a := width`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a clown :)